# Sort by / Order by time stored in database "00:00 - 23:00"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out an sql query that would allow me to sort data ascending order depending on what time is sorted in appointment_time column, it has values like "00:00" - "23:00"

In my head it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY appointment_time ASC
```

But I don't know how to make it understand that 00:00 is lower value than 00:01 for example and so on.

Comment: What database are you using?  And what is the datatype of the `appointment_time` field?  Guessing it's a string.

Comment: @GoatCO Sqlite and it is a string indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will sort fine as your query is written, easiest thing is to just give it a whirl and see what happens:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY appointment_time ASC
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fdb0e/1/0)

Alphanumeric ordering has no problem with numbers stored in strings so long as they are zero padded, as is the case with your times.

Comment: I'll try it out, what I thought is that this ":" symbol in-between numbers would screw it up.

Comment: @Ilja As long as they are consistent in format it's no issue.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know how to make it understand that 00:00 is lower value than 00:01

If all you have is a time then an alphabetical sort should work just fine.  If you *want* to convert to a DateTime you can use CONVERT:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, appointment_time , 108)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store from_time and to_time as DATETIME (in two separate columns), the sorting will be done correctly by the DB.

It will also take into consideration the date part as well, i.e. sort **1 Jan 2014 23:00** before **31 Dec 2013 23:30**. If you really aren't interested in the date, use a dummy date for all entries and just use the time part of the column.

Comment: I think you've confused the question, I don't believe OP indicates there are multiple time values in one column here.

Comment: Then just use a single column. The correct typing of the column still solves the issue.